# Обратиться к ячейкам текущей книги после открытия другой

Tags: excel, vba

Мне необходимо считать значения из другой книги Excel с помощью макроса в текущей и записать в нее значения.
После того, как я открываю книгу так:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
```

Или так:

```
With Workbooks.Open(path)
'...
End With
```

Все содержимое внутри кода до закрытия файла относится к новооткрытой книге, то есть:

```
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
With .Worksheets(1) ; .Range("A1")
Cells(1, 1)
```

Выполняют ровно одну и ту же работу обращаясь к открытой из макроса книге. А нужно, чтобы `Cells` относились к текущему листу в текущей книге, из которой запущен макрос, а обращение через точку вытягивало данные из открытой книги. Что я делаю не так?

P.S. `ThisWorkbook`, к сожалению, не работает, можно ли решить это как-то по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub jjj()
    Dim wb0 As Workbook, wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, sText As String, sPath As String
    
    ' .......................
    Set wb0 = ThisWorkbook

    ' sPath = ....
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)
    
    i = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    sText = wb0.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
    
    ' .......................
    Set wb0 = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: На `ThisWorkbook` вылетает ошибка `ActiveX component can't create object`, нужно как-то без воркбука попытаться

Comment: Что-то не так делаете или не все рассказываете... Покажите пример с кодом....

Comment: Программа падает при отладке на любой строчке с упоминанием `ThisWorkbook`, так что нет смысла код приводить. Например, банальное `Dim cwb As Workbook \ Set cwb = ThisWorkbook` уже падает

Comment: А полное имя Application.ThisWorkbook? Что, `Debug.Print  Application.ThisWorkbook.Name` тоже ругнётся?

Comment: *Программа падает при отладке на любой строчке с упоминанием ThisWorkbook* -  такого быть не должно. То ли размещаете код непонятно где, то ли записано непонятно как, то ли проблемы с книгой... Создайте новую книгу, в ней в общий модуль запишите показанный макрос, запишите в переменную путь к другой книге и проверьте работоспособность обращения к книге. Если работает, создайте небольшой пример на основе Вашей рабочей книги, иначе - стреляние с закрытыми глазами по воробьям и гадание по направлению ветра